# ID is gone when I refresh a NextJS Dynamic Route page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to get dynamic routing working in order to display and retrieve the right information using the id from the url. This works when I visit the page, but when I reload the page the id is blank. Is this fixable? I couldn't find a answer for it on the internet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Code for reference

```
//Initializing router
const router = useRouter();

//Getting id from url
const { id } = router.query;

//Fetching postdata
  const getPostData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    await db
      .collection("Posts")
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          setPostData(doc.data());
          setLoading(false);
        } else {
          //router.push("/404");
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        //router.push("/404");
      });
  };
```

Comment: Could you share the code in order to see what's wrong?

Comment: @MihaiMoraru, Yea sorry. I edited the post.

Comment: It is strongly recommended to use `getServerSideProps` and export that in the file where the component is defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known caveat about Next.js routing, you can read about it [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats).

Anyway, add this on your page that uses router.query:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    return {
        props: {},
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am hosting my site on Firebase. Is this still gonna work?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter where you host it, will work the same.

Comment: I don't think this will work if you are not running next.js with a server-side rendering on.

Comment: If you don't run next.js with SSR on, you might not have the problem in the first place

Comment: Can you please have a look on this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70211088/next-js-shows-index-page-content-on-refresh-dynamic-page-url

Answer (score -1):

You can save to localstorage the id the first time, and get that item if query.id is undefined, look at this approach:

```
query.id && localStorage.setItem('lastId', query.id)
const id = query.id || localStorage.getItem('lastId')
```